# Count Django objects where two fields are equal

Tags: django

Let's say I have the following Django model:

```
class Point(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
```

I want a count of objects where `x == y`. I know I can do it in Python:

```
count = 0
for point in Point.objects.all():
    if point.x == point.y:
        count += 1
```

However, my table contains millions of records so I want to do this in the database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all `Point` instances where the `x` and `y` are equal and output the count like this:

```
from django.db.models import F
count = Point.objects.filter(x=F('y')).count()
```

Comment: Corresponding documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters